# Find a matrix which satisfies certain constraints

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Another description of the problem: [Compute a matrix which satisfies certain constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787848/compute-a-matrix-which-satisfies-certain-constraints?noredirect=1#comment76560638_44787848)

Given a function whose only argument is a 4x4 matrix (`int[4][4] matrix`), determine the maximal possible output (return value) of that function.

The 4x4 matrix must satisfy the following constraints:

1. All entries are integers between -10 and 10 (inclusively).
2. It must be symmetrix, entry(x,y) = entry(y,x).
3. Diagonal entries must be positive, entry(x,x) > 0.
4. The sum of all 16 entries must be 0.

The function must only sum up values of the matrix, nothing fancy.

**My question:**

Given such a function which sums up certain values of a matrix (matrix satisfies above constraints), how do I find the maximal possible output/return value of that function?

For example:

```
/* The function sums up certain values of the matrix, 
   a value can be summed up multiple or 0 times. */

// for this example I arbitrarily chose values at (0,0), (1,2), (0,3), (1,1).
int exampleFunction(int[][] matrix) {
    int a = matrix[0][0];
    int b = matrix[1][2];
    int c = matrix[0][3];
    int d = matrix[1][1];

    return a+b+c+d;
}

/* The result (max output of the above function) is 40, 
   it can be achieved by the following matrix: */
    0.   1.   2.   3.
0.  10  -10  -10   10
1. -10   10   10  -10
2. -10   10    1   -1
3.  10  -10   -1    1


// Another example:

// for this example I arbitrarily chose values at (0,3), (0,1), (0,1), (0,4), ...
int exampleFunction2(int[][] matrix) {
    int a = matrix[0][3] + matrix[0][1] + matrix[0][1];
    int b = matrix[0][3] + matrix[0][3] + matrix[0][2];
    int c = matrix[1][2] + matrix[2][1] + matrix[3][1];
    int d = matrix[1][3] + matrix[2][3] + matrix[3][2];

    return a+b+c+d;
}

/* The result (max output of the above function) is -4, it can be achieved by 
   the following matrix:  */
    0.   1.   2.   3.
0.   1   10   10  -10
1.  10    1   -1  -10
2.  10   -1    1   -1
3. -10  -10   -1    1
```

I don't know where to start. Currently I'm trying to estimate the number of 4x4 matrices which satisfy the constraints, if the number is small enough the problem could be solved by brute force.

Is there a more general approach?
Can the solution to this problem be generalized such that it can be easily adapted to arbitrary functions on the given matrix and arbitrary constraints for the matrix?

Comment: What exactly is the value to be maximized with respect to the mentioned conditions? Or is this part of the problem?

Comment: @Codor The return value of the function is to be maximized. In other words: the function chooses which entries to sum up, the goal is to come up with a matrix for which this sum is maximal.

Comment: Note that the matrix is actually 'smaller' than an arbitrary matrix due to the symmetry; there are not 16 potentially different entries, but only 10.

Comment: What does the function supposed to return ? Is it sum of `n` number of elements where `n` can be anything , I mean `n <= 16` ? Also what do you want the output to be ? is it the matrix or the maximum value ? Please frame your question to get better help.

Comment: Have you tried [the simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)?

Comment: What does _sum up certain values_ mean?  The function can choose just the positive entries?

Comment: @svasa The function sums up `n` elements from the matrix where `1 <= n < Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the elements can be any elements from the matrix. For the output: "determine the maximal possible output (return value) of that function", I am looking for the maximum value.

Comment: @AndrewS With *sum up certain values* I mean the entries from the matrix which the function sums up. Those entries can be any entries from the matrix but a function can pick a finite amount of them. It would be more precise to say *sum up certain entries*, my bad.

Comment: What do you mean `n < Integer.MAX_VALUE` ? The matrix has only 16 elements.

Comment: @svasa "The function sums up certain entries of the matrix, 
   an entry can be summed up **multiple or 0 times**."

Comment: Then get the maximum value and multiply it by Integer.MAX_VALUE, there is something not correct with the problem description.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz how woud you apply the simplex algorithm to this problem?

Comment: @svasa what are you trying to achieve by that multiplication?

Comment: @svasa We are not talking about one specific function. The given function represents entries of the matrix which one has to sum up, the number of entries can be arbitrary. The goal is to determine the maximum value which can be achieved by summing up the specified entries for any possible matrix which satisfies the constraints.

Comment: @svasa A refined version of the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787848/compute-a-matrix-which-satisfies-certain-constraints,  does it make sense now?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to solve this using [linear programming techniques](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog).

The idea is to express the problem as some inequalities, some equalities, and a linear objective function and then call a library to optimize the result.

Python code:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
c = [0]*16
def use(y,x):
    c[y*4+x] -= 1

if 0:
    use(0,0)
    use(1,2)
    use(0,3)
    use(1,1)
else:
    use(0,3)
    use(0,1)
    use(0,1)
    use(0,3)
    use(0,3)
    use(0,2)
    use(1,2)
    use(2,1)
    use(3,1)
    use(1,3)
    use(2,3)
    use(3,2)
bounds=[ [-10,10] for i in range(4*4) ]
for i in range(4):
    bounds[i*4+i] = [1,10]
A_eq = [[1] * 16]
b_eq = [0]
for x in range(4):
    for y in range(x+1,4):
        D = [0]*16
        D[x*4+y] = 1
        D[y*4+x] = -1
        A_eq.append(D)
        b_eq.append(0)

r = opt.linprog(c,A_eq=A_eq,b_eq=b_eq,bounds=bounds)
for y in range(4):
    print r.x[4*y:4*y+4]
print -r.fun
```

This prints:

```
[  1.  10. -10.  10.]
[ 10.   1.   8. -10.]
[-10.   8.   1. -10.]
[ 10. -10. -10.   1.]
16.0
```

saying that the best value for your second case is 16, with the given matrix.

Strictly speaking you are wanting integer solutions.  Linear programming solves this type of problem when the inputs can be any real values, while integer programming solves this type when the inputs must be integers.

In your case you may well find that the linear programming method already provides integer solutions (it does for the two given examples).  When this happens, it is certain that this is the optimal answer.

However, if the variables are not integral you may need to find an integer programming library instead.

Comment: In the last sentence, did you mean "linear" rather than "integer"?

Comment: I'm doing this out of fun and practice, the solution should be in java and I don't want to use any 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first consider what matrices will satisfy the rules. The 4 numbers on the diagonal must be positive, with the minimal sum of the diagonal being 4 (four 1 values), and the maximum being 40 (four 10 values).

The total sum of all 16 items is 0 - or to put it another way, sum(diagnoal)+sum(rest-of-matrix)=0.

Since you know that sum(diagonal) is positive, that means that sum(rest-of-matrix) must be negative and equal - basically sum(diagonal)*(-1).

We also know that the rest of the matrix is symmetrical - so you're guaranteed the sum(rest-of-matrix) is an even number. That means that the diagonal must also be an even number, and the sum of the top half of the matrix is exactly half the diagonal*(-1).

For any given function, you take a handful of cells and sum them. Now you can consider the functions as fitting into categories. For functions that take all 4 cells from the diagonal only, the maximum will be 40. If the function takes all 12 cells which are not the diagonal, the maximum is -4 (negative minimal diagonal).

Other categories of functions that have an easy answer:

1) one from the diagonal and an entire half of the matrix above/below the diagonal - the max is 3. The diagonal cell will be 10, the rest will be 1, 1, 2 (minimal to get to an even number) and the half-matrix will sum at -7.

2) two cells of the diagonal and half a matrix - the max is 9. the two diagonal cells are maximised to two tens, the remaining cells are 1,1 - and so the half matrix sums at -11.

3) three cells from the diagonal and half a matrix - the max is 14.

4) the entire diagonal and half the matrix - the max is 20.

You can continue with the categories of selecting functions (using some from the diagonal and some from the rest), and easily calculating the maximum for each category of selecting function. I believe they can all be mapped.

Then the only step is to put your new selecting function in the correct category and you know the maximum.

Comment: "If they come from only the rest of the matrix, reach for -4 (negative minimal diagonal)." Why? If I have a function that sums up cell(1,0) only, then there is a matrix for which the sum is 10 (take the matrix from example 2).

Comment: That's a fair point. I'll revise my answer tomorrow to include a clearer algorithm.

Comment: I came to some similar conclusions, there are counterexamples for your matrix-to-max mappings since It is possible that the function sums up over 16 entries (it sums up some of them multiple times). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787848/compute-a-matrix-which-satisfies-certain-constraints?noredirect=1#comment76560638_44787848 for a clearer description of the problem.

Comment: I assumed each cell must only appear in the sum once. If that's not the case, then you cannot use most of my solution.

Comment: See example 2, some cells appear multiple times inside of the sum.

Comment: Your approach might still work, the sums won't be constants as you described them but will depend on the summands chosen by the function.

Comment: True, but the benefit of my approach is that with some small pre-calculation you could classify the selecting function and know the max sum - without having to input any matrices, using only the known constraints. When you can select the same cell more than once the constraints become less useful and any solution will require some tests on input matrices, which gets us closer to a brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the elements in the matrix in descending order and store in an array.Iterate through the elements in the array one by one 
and add it to a variable.Stop iterating at the point when adding an element to variable decrease its value.The value stored in the variable gives maximum value.

```
maxfunction(matrix[][])
{
array(n)=sortDescending(matrix[][]);
max=n[0];
i=1;
    for i to n do
     temp=max;
     max=max+n[i];
     if(max<temp)
       break;

return max;
}
```